# Passing multiple php variable using img src url

Tags: php, image, variables, url, src

I am new to PHP. Creating an application with multiple page.

Sample1.php

```
$queue=$_POST['element_3'];//Customer name
$month=(int)$_POST['month'];//month as value 06
$std_yy = $_POST['year'];// 2016
<img src="trend_g.php?element_3=$queue&month=$std_mm&year=$std_yy" /> //does not work
<img src="trend_g.php?element_3=Apple&month=06&year=2016" />//works
```

trend_g.php

```
$queue=$_GET['element_3'];
$month=(int)$_GET['month'];
$std_yy = $_GET['year'];
```

Please help me to pass the variables through URL. Also I did try the below too.

```
<img src="trend_g.php?element_3='.$queue.'&month='.$std_mm.'&year='.$std_yy.'" /> //didnt work.
```

Looked into various options, but I am stuck here. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `$month=(int)$_POST['month'];//month as value 06` this would change 06 to 6

Comment: Thank you for responding! Still no change.. trend_g.php gives out the graph by calculating with the values passed on. If I pass the values directly it works but not as php variables ie $queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the img element as PHP while still in PHP, ie before the closing PHP tag (?>)

change

```
<img src="trend_g.php?element_3=$queue&month=$std_mm&year=$std_yy" />

<img src="trend_g.php?element_3=Apple&month=06&year=2016" />
```

to

```
echo '<img src="trend_g.php?element_3='.$queue.'&month='.$std_mm.'&year='.$std_yy.'" /> ';

echo '<img src="trend_g.php?element_3=Apple&month=06&year=2016" />';
```

**EDIT**

If you did close off the php then you need to change

```
<img src="trend_g.php?element_3=$queue&month=$std_mm&year=$std_yy" />
```

To

```
<img src="trend_g.php?element_3=<?php echo $queue;?>&month=<?php echo $std_mm;?>&year=<?php echo $std_yy;?>" />
```

Comment: Oh i did close the php tags before the img tag... and then starts the html

Comment: @SaranyaThirumeni I've made an edit to the answer to cover that

Comment: That worked :) Thank you so much! So why is such variation and what does it do internally? So the one which I used does not pass the value at all?

Comment: it's because you closed the PHP tag and tried to use PHP code without opening it again. If you tried it outside of an element, it would have just printed the variables you tried to pass on the screen instead of running through the code. I prefer the first method I posted because it saves opening and closing php multiple times and is easier to manage, but either work fine.

Comment: Got it! :) Thank you for the explanation